# importance of JS to help me to decide to use or not the TEMPLATE LAYOUT MODULE (css3)

Tags: layout, css

I would like to use this JS plugin to use the CSS template layout :
http://code.google.com/p/css-template-layout/

But I know that it is recommended to first have a website working without JS. So, my project consist in doing a tourism website...will I lose a lot of 'potential user' if JS is required to visit my website ?

Tkx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About 4% of my visitors don't have javascript support includes bots though, that would explain quite a few percent. There are a few classes of browser that won't run your javascript as intended:

```
Screen readers/accessible browsers (like for blind people)
Mobile browsers
Console-based browsers (Used sometimes by sysadmins from servers with no gui installed)
Off-brand browsers or older browsers with buggy javascript engines
Search Engines (Google)
```

I don't think that many people just turn javascript off anymore. However, things like NoScript --where javascript is disabled for a site initially and must be explicitly enabled-- are becoming more popular.
The problem is more apparent on mobile browsers, but you will likely serve different content to them anyway.

Comment: Ok, so for mobile phone developpement, it is also recommended to have a website working without JS ?

Comment: No, You have to use a mobile detection mechanism and serve different content for older mobile browsers that does not support javascript.